# MySQL: ON UPDATE CASCADE for a simple table "id|parent|text", not possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Tree` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `Tree` (`id`, `parent`, `text`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1'),
(2, 1, '1.1'),
(3, 1, '1.2'),
(4, 1, '1.3');

ALTER TABLE `Tree` ADD CONSTRAINT `tree_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `tree` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

After having executed all of the above statements a problem observed for the following one:

```
UPDATE  `Tree` SET  `id` =  '10' WHERE  `Tree`.`id` = 1
```

While it is expected that changing the main id would cause all linked `parent` records to update automatically due to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` constraint. Aren't these cascading referential integrity constraints are all about?

Comment: I'd expect a constraint error on the primary key, myself. You can't have two rows with an id = 2.

Comment: Oooups, technical mistake, you get the problem when you are trying to set id = 10, thanks by the way

Comment: You say "After having executed all of the above statements a problem observed..." What kind of problem is observed? Did you try the statement? Does it cause an error message? What is the result?

Comment: #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`tree`, CONSTRAINT `tree_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `tree` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) say the following (emphasis mine):

> Deviation from SQL standards: If ON
>   UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL
>   recurses to update the same table it
>   has previously updated during the
>   cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. **This
>   means that you cannot use
>   self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE or
>   ON UPDATE SET NULL operations**. This is
>   to prevent infinite loops resulting
>   from cascaded updates. A
>   self-referential ON DELETE SET NULL,
>   on the other hand, is possible, as is
>   a self-referential ON DELETE CASCADE.
>   Cascading operations may not be nested
>   more than 15 levels deep.

Comment: Uh-oh. A big gotcha and limitation of MySQL. Some people simply suggest `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` without knowing this. Good catch!

Comment: I would rather avoid the use of foreign key in this situation, and manually use `UPDATE Tree set Parent=10 WHERE Parent=1` instead.