# ERROR 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: sql, cascade, mysql-error-1451

```
CREATE  TABLE `categories` (
  `idcategories` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `idparent` INT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcategories`) );

ALTER TABLE `categories` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_idparent`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idparent` )
  REFERENCES `ilmercatinodelpulcino`.`categories` (`idcategories` )
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
, ADD INDEX `FK_idparent` (`idparent` ASC) ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`idcategories`, `description`)
    VALUES (1, 'cat1');
INSERT INTO `categories` (`idcategories`, `idparent`, `description`)
    VALUES (2, 1, 'cat1_child');
```

So this table represents a category, with an ID and a self pointing parent ID.
I have inserted a category cat1 and a subcategory cat1_child with parent id of cat1.

Now, I want to be able to change idcategory of cat1 from 1 to 10 and because I set the foreign key on update CASCADE, I expect that idparent of cat1_child will be set to 10 as well.
But when I do:

```
UPDATE `categories` SET `idcategories`=10 WHERE `idcategories`='1';
```

I get an error:

> ERROR 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`categories`, CONSTRAINT `FK_idparent` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`idparent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`idcategories`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) SQL Statement: UPDATE `categories` SET
>   `idcategories`=10 WHERE `idcategories`='1'

The delete instead work as expected and deleting cat1, cat1_child will be deleted as well.

Where is the error?
Than you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: ON UPDATE CASCADE for a simple table "id|parent|text", not possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446517/mysql-on-update-cascade-for-a-simple-table-idparenttext-not-possible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the answer is in the [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) (scroll down to the bottom):

> **Deviation from SQL standards**: If `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE SET
>   NULL` recurses to update the same table it has previously updated
>   during the cascade, it acts like `RESTRICT`. This means that you cannot
>   use self-referential `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE SET NULL`
>   operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded
>   updates. A self-referential `ON DELETE SET NULL`, on the other hand, is
>   possible, as is a self-referential `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Cascading
>   operations may not be nested more than 15 levels deep.

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e29db/1

Comment: Thank You. Is there any warkaround to do what I want to?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue then i disabled the foreign key check using below query and then i was able to delete the row

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

You can also enable the foreign key check using below query

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```