# How to update FK linked to multiple table - Cascade on Update

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, cascade, referential-integrity

I have 3 tables which are linked to each other

1. task
2. client
3. compliance

The relationship is as shown in diagram below 
[image: relationship]

The `compliance` table has the foreign key as below
[image: compliance table]

The `task` table has the foreign key as below
[image: task table]

Issue:
When I edit/update `clientno` in `client` table, I get

```
1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`task`, CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`officeid`, `clientid`) REFERENCES `client` (`officeid`, `clientno`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

I expected that when `clientno` was changed in `client` table, the same will be updated in both `complaince` and `task` table.

I guess I am hitting a known limitation of InnoDB engine. Which goes not allow cascading updates to FK. If this is true, then what is the solution to updating the 3 tables with new `clientno`?

**EDIT 1:** As pointed out by @pankaj, how to overcome

> If ON UPDATE CASCADE recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT. This means that you cannot use self-referential ON UPDATE CASCADE operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates.

**Edit 2:**

```
create table client
(
  officeid     char(6)                 not null,
  clientno     char(10)                not null,
  fname        varchar(40)             not null,
  primary key (officeid, clientno)
);

create index officeid_clientno
  on client (officeid, clientno);


create table compliance
(
  officeid    char(6)                   not null,
  id          smallint(5) unsigned      not null,
  clientid    char(10)                  not null,
  primary key (officeid, id),
  constraint compliance_ibfk_2
  foreign key (officeid, clientid) references client (officeid, clientno)
    on update cascade
    on delete cascade
);

create index officeid_clientid
  on compliance (officeid, clientid, id);


create table task
(
  officeid        char(6)                      not null,
  taskno          char(10)                     not null,
  clientid        char(10)                     not null,
  taskname        varchar(50)                  not null,
  complianceid    smallint(5) unsigned         null,
  primary key (officeid, taskno),
  constraint task_ibfk_1
  foreign key (officeid, clientid) references client (officeid, clientno)
    on update cascade,
  constraint task_ibfk_4
  foreign key (officeid, clientid, complianceid) references compliance (officeid, clientid, id)
    on update cascade
);

create index officeid_clientid_complianceid
  on task (officeid, clientid, complianceid);
```

FYI: I tried in mariadb 10.3 as well as mysql 8.0

Comment: This may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5446693/4050261

Comment: @GMB, added table create statements

Comment: Creating a foreign key from `task` to `compliance` that includes `officeid` and `clientid` doesn't make sense, since you have already included those columns in a foreign key to `client` (which is the appropriate table) (and `compliance` already has that same foreign key relationship). You should change that foreign key to only be on `complianceid`

Comment: Issue reproduced on MariaDB 10.3 in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=acb279456887b2313542864638489fa8)

Comment: @Nick, this will cause record in `Task` Table to be liked to a record in `Compliance` Table which is not of the same `clientid`

Comment: @AdarshMadrecha that can't happen if your inserts are consistent.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the way relationships are declared.

First of all, as commented by @Nick, there is no need for a relation between `task` and `client`, as this is already covered by the relation to `compliance`. Commenting the declaration of this superfluous constraint is enough the make the error disappear, as you can see in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4642ec0f9c9956530464dce3148e117e).

```
create table task
(
  officeid        char(6)                      not null,
  ...
  primary key (officeid, taskno),
  -- constraint task_ibfk_1
   -- foreign key (officeid, clientid) references client (officeid, clientno)
   -- on update cascade,
  constraint task_ibfk_4
  foreign key (officeid, clientid, complianceid) references compliance (officeid,     clientid, id)
    on update cascade
);
```

Another suggestion is to use an autoincremented primary key in all tables (you can use an `UNIQUE` index to enforce composite referential integrity rules). This is the most usual way to proceed with MySQL, with which handling relationships is pretty straighforward.

Comment: Not all tasks are linked via `Compliance` table to `Client` table. Hence `complianceid` can be null in `Task` table. Thanks for creating fiddle. I have added my sql statements . https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=784cdf9389eae69eead1830267b2afda

Comment: I agree with @AdarshMadrecha, the 2 FK are required. 1st to `Client` table and Another to `Complaince` table using `clientid & complianceid`

Answer (score 0):

**I think that your problem stems from using mutable fields as primary keys**

You can mitigate this by using a surrogate immutable primary key and adding a unique key to your mutable fields. You should be able to apply the same constraints as before without compromising data integrity

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE client (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY,
  officeid CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  clientno CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  fname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uq-client-officeid-clientno IN client (officeid, clientno);

CREATE TABLE compliance (
  id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY,
  client_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk-compliance-client-id FOREIGN KEY id 
    REFERENCES client (id)
);

CREATE INDEX ix-compliance-id-client_id IN compliance (id, client_id);

CREATE TABLE task (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO-INCREMENT PRIMARY,
  client_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  compliance_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NULL,
  taskno CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  taskname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk-task-client-id FOREIGN KEY id 
    REFERENCES client (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk-task-compliance-id-client_id FOREIGN KEY (compliance_id, client_id) 
    REFERENCES compliance (id, client_id)
);
```

This table structure mimics your current constraints and will allow you to update a `clientno` without needing the cascades

**Note** the foreign key `fk-task-compliance-id-client_id` which makes sure the compliance referenced by a task contains the correct `client_id`

I would also consider a separate table, office, with a surrogate integer primary key and containing the character based `officeid`. This could then be reference by the client table