# I can't update a table record with foreign key in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a simple MYSQL table with two columns named id and parent_id. I've created the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories(
  id                        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  parent_id                 INT DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES categories(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

In this example I need that the foreign key(parent_id) and its reference(id) to be in the same table.

I've put two records into the table like this:

record1 id=1 parent_id=1

record2 id=2 parent_id=1

now I want to change the id of the record1 from id=1 to id=3. I expected that the two parent_id values to change to 3 also, but MYSQL shows this error message:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nullsegm_db`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Could you post the request you are trying to execute so we can fix it easily. Looking at the error you have it looks like you are trying to use a `parent_id` which does not match with an existing `id` of your `categories` table. This breaks your constraint

Comment: I am pretty confused for what you need a foreign key on a column of the same table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: ON UPDATE CASCADE for a simple table "id|parent|text", not possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446517/mysql-on-update-cascade-for-a-simple-table-idparenttext-not-possible)

Comment: Self-referencing `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not allowed and acts like `ON UPDATE RESTRICT`. See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html) (second paragraph).

Comment: the parent_id column shows a sub category that its parent has the id equal to the parent_id value. at some situations I maybe need to change the id manually and I want that the all sub categories change their parent category id to the new id automatically.

Comment: @CherryDT Yes, I think its meaningless that MYSQL can not do that. what's the alternate approach in some situations like this? I do not want to use a separate table for parent_id.

Comment: You can remove the foreign key constraint and implement the cascaded updates/deletions yourself, manually, either in a transaction on the main update or in a custom trigger.